# How to aggregate properly with stream() java 8 and set pageable

Tags: java, spring-mvc, java-8, java-stream

I am working on a Rest app where I need to return data from a db but sorted as : 
* page
* version 
* aggregate per company

here is my data :

```
id  date    company code    page  version

4   1,49E+12    TOTO 1  FR  RFQ DISTRIBUTOR
8   1,49E+12    TOTO 1  FR  RFQ DISTRIBUTOR
12  1,49E+12    TOTO 1  FR  RFQ DISTRIBUTOR
32  1,49E+12    TOTO 2  FR  RFQ DISTRIBUTOR
56  1,49E+12    TOTO 2  FR  RFQ DISTRIBUTOR
57  1,49E+12    TOTO 2  FR  RFQ DISTRIBUTOR
78  1,49E+12    TOTO 2  FR  RFQ DISTRIBUTOR
84  1,49E+12    TOTO 3  FR  RFQ DISTRIBUTOR
87  1,49E+12    TOTO 3  FR  RFQ DISTRIBUTOR
151 1,49E+12    TOTO 4  DE  RFQ DISTRIBUTOR
155 1,49E+12    TOTO 4  DE  RFQ DISTRIBUTOR
159 1,49E+12    TOTO 4  DE  RFQ DISTRIBUTOR
169 1,49E+12    TOTO 5  DE  RFQ DISTRIBUTOR
```

I need to return the information as :

```
id  date    company code    page  version

4   1,49E+12    TOTO 1  FR  RFQ DISTRIBUTOR
32  1,49E+12    TOTO 2  FR  RFQ DISTRIBUTOR
84  1,49E+12    TOTO 3  FR  RFQ DISTRIBUTOR
151 1,49E+12    TOTO 4  DE  RFQ DISTRIBUTOR
169 1,49E+12    TOTO 5  DE  RFQ DISTRIBUTOR
```

Here is my code :

```
@Override
public ServiceOut list(final Pageable pageable) {
    logger.debug("pageable: {} ", pageable);

    String page = "RFQ";

    final List<Statistics> stats = super.statisticsRepository.findAll();
    List<Statistics> resultStream = new ArrayList<>(stats);

    Map<String, List<Statistics>> list = stats.stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getPageVisited().equals(page))
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Statistics::getCompanyName, Collectors.toList()));

    int start = pageable.getOffset();
    int end = (start + pageable.getPageSize()) > resultStream.size() ? resultStream.size() : (start + pageable.getPageSize());

    Page<Statistics> pages = new PageImpl<Statistics>(resultStream.subList(start, end), pageable, resultStream.size());

    final List<StatisticsOut> statisticsOuts = new ArrayList<>(resultStream.size());

    final StatisticsOut statisticsOut = new StatisticsOut();
    statisticsOut.setContent(pages.getContent());
    statisticsOut.setNumber(pages.getNumber());
    statisticsOut.setNumberOfElements(pages.getNumberOfElements());
    statisticsOut.setTotalElements(pages.getTotalElements());
    statisticsOut.setTotalPages(pages.getTotalPages());
    statisticsOut.setSize(pages.getSize());
    statisticsOut.setSort(pages.getSort());
    statisticsOut.setNextPageable(pages.nextPageable());

    statisticsOuts.add(statisticsOut);

    final ServiceOut out = new ServiceOut(ServiceOut.Status.SUCCESS);
    out.setStatistics(statisticsOuts);

    return out;
}
```

First : I wanted to convert my Map into List in order to set properly the "new PageImpl"
Secondly : looks like when a do a logger.debug on Map> list, the output seems coherent but I can't parse datas into the Page

Actually I am desperate and if someone could help, I will appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something and produced same result. i hope, it will help you

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Statictics> statictics = new ArrayList<>();
        statictics.add(new Statictics(4, new Date(), "TOTO", 1, "FR", "RFQ DISTRIBUTOR"));
        statictics.add(new Statictics(8, new Date(), "TOTO", 1, "FR", "RFQ DISTRIBUTOR"));
        statictics.add(new Statictics(12, new Date(), "TOTO", 1, "FR", "RFQ DISTRIBUTOR"));
        statictics.add(new Statictics(32, new Date(), "TOTO", 2, "FR", "RFQ DISTRIBUTOR"));
        statictics.add(new Statictics(56, new Date(), "TOTO", 2, "FR", "RFQ DISTRIBUTOR"));
        statictics.add(new Statictics(57, new Date(), "TOTO", 2, "FR", "RFQ DISTRIBUTOR"));
        statictics.add(new Statictics(78, new Date(), "TOTO", 2, "FR", "RFQ DISTRIBUTOR"));
        statictics.add(new Statictics(84, new Date(), "TOTO", 3, "FR", "RFQ DISTRIBUTOR"));
        statictics.add(new Statictics(87, new Date(), "TOTO", 3, "FR", "RFQ DISTRIBUTOR"));
        statictics.add(new Statictics(151, new Date(), "TOTO", 4, "FR", "RFQ DISTRIBUTOR"));
        statictics.add(new Statictics(155, new Date(), "TOTO", 4, "FR", "RFQ DISTRIBUTOR"));
        statictics.add(new Statictics(159, new Date(), "TOTO", 4, "FR", "RFQ DISTRIBUTOR"));
        statictics.add(new Statictics(169, new Date(), "TOTO", 5, "FR", "RFQ DISTRIBUTOR"));

        statictics.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Statictics::getCode))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> e.getValue().get(0))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static class Statictics {
        int id;
        Date date;
        String company;
        int code;
        String page;
        String version;

        public Statictics(int id, Date date, String company, int code, String page, String version) {
            this.id = id;
            this.date = date;
            this.company = company;
            this.code = code;
            this.page = page;
            this.version = version;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "id : " + id + " code : " + code;
        }

        public int getCode() {
            return code;
        }
    }
```

And here is my result

```
id : 4 code : 1
id : 32 code : 2
id : 84 code : 3
id : 151 code : 4
id : 169 code : 5
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Maybe you could help me to optimized my code cause I am pretty sure I can reduce much more the huge function that I wrote with stream() and aggregate functionnality :